# Multiple UITableView in one ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Why not triggered after **else**?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (tableView == self.tabFourContacts)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ContactCell";
    ContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([self.contactsArray[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"tel_"]){
        cell.labelContact.text = [self.contactsArray[indexPath.row] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"tel_" withString:@""];
        cell.iconContact.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_tab4_contacts_phone.png"];
    }

    ...

    if ([self.contactsArray[indexPath.row] hasPrefix:@"addr_"]){
        cell.labelContact.text = [self.contactsArray[indexPath.row] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"addr_" withString:@""];
        cell.iconContact.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_tab4_contacts_address.png"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    return cell;
}
else
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedbackCell";
    FeedbackCell * cellFeedback = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Feedback * feedbackObject;
    feedbackObject = [feedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cellFeedback.feedNameLabel.text = feedbackObject.name;
    cellFeedback.feedDateLabel.text = feedbackObject.date;
    cellFeedback.feedTextLabel.text = feedbackObject.feedback;

    if ([feedbackObject.isGood isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
        cellFeedback.feedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_ratingup_green.png"];
    }
    if ([feedbackObject.isGood isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
        cellFeedback.feedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_ratingdown_red.png"];
    }
    return cellFeedback;
}
}
```

If for the second case to specify an `if` or `else if (tableView == self.tabFiveFeedbacks)`, the method requests to return cell; it was stated clearly out of the equation...

Added NSLog to check `numberOfRowsInSection:` for both tableview's:

```
2015-06-02 22:41:08.052 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.052 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.053 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.053 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.061 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab2: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.061 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab1: 0
2015-06-02 22:41:08.217 MyApp[27994:1093141] numRowsForTab1: 1
```

Is it correct that NSLog call 3-4 times for each section?

Comment: one opening `{` is missing. are you sure that is your real code?

Comment: Post all the code so it is easier to understand your question. The cell variable doesn't just appear from nowhere I'm sure.

Comment: You just need a code ViewController? There 52569 characters...

Comment: first you need to check delegates and you need to check what happens in `numberofrowsinsection` code to understand you prolblem.

Comment: Both TableView's are delegated to ViewController. I just check this. I'll edit question with NSLog from numverofrowsinsection for both tableviews

Comment: If u post as answer, i'll mark it correct ("need to check numberofrowsinsection")

Comment: as you can see in your log only tab1 finally have a row, which would be your "tabFourContacts" table, thats why onlu if part is called not else part. for each section `numberofrowsinsection` will be called once unless you reload the table or section.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this, if you go this way. And also do the sam with the other delegates.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtindexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
        //configure the cell for tableView1
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifierForCell1" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text for cell tableView 1"
    } else if (tableView == self.tableView2) {
        //configure the cell for tableView2
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifierForCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text for cell tableView 2"
    } else {
        //configure the cell for any other tableView
        //the cell object will never be nil,
        //it will always fall back to here.
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifierForAnyOtherCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text for any other cell"
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Replace `self.tableView1` with your own tableView (and tableView2 if needed)

Keep in mind that you should set the delegate of ALL the `UITableView`s to this `UIViewController`

```
self.tableView1.delegate = self;
self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
self.tableView2.delegate = self;
self.tableView2.dataSource = self;
```